# What is the design of JBoss log manager design in wildfly 17?

Tags: wildfly, jboss-logging

From the documentation I understand that it supports multiple frameworks like log4j, log4jv2 and slf4j. log4j/log4jv2/slf4j are only the API interfaces and the actual logging will be done by the  jboss-logmanager classes located in the "org.jboss.log4j.logmanager" module? If that is the case what is the logger implementation used by jboss-logmanager.

Comment: log4j2 and slf4j support multiple backend implementations out of the box (and both come with their preferred default). For log4j they probably just did some bytecode hacking (or maybe even just configuration of log4j) to get a similar result, as that one wasn't built with replaceable backends in mind.

Comment: Thanks @Generous Badger. I see that they use a shaded jar within their log4j backend implementation : https://github.com/jboss-logging/log4j-jboss-logmanager/blob/main/pom.xml#L120, though the details of what they are doing is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Logging in WildFly is configured via the [jboss-logmanager](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/tree/2.1). This is an extension of JUL and does not use log4j or any other log manager. The `org.jboss.log4j.logmanager` module you reference is like a log4j facade in that it replaces the log4j log manager to write to the jboss-logmanager.

WildFly itself uses [jboss-logging](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logging). This is simply a logging facade like slf4j.